# playing low frequency heartbeat signal through mobile speaker

Tags: android, audio, audio-processing, time-frequency

I am making an app to listen to heartbeat . I could listen to  filtered heartbeat signal through headset but not through mobile speaker as the mobile speaker doesn't support such low frequencies , I tried frequency shifting , but it results in a sharper tones .

I need help in playing my output signal through mobile speaker, but without the sharper tone.

Any help is appreciated